# LiveServerTestCase slow

Tags: python, django, performance, testing

Approximately 1 time out of 4, when I try to run my functional tests, I've to wait like 20 minutes for my tests to start :

```
python manage.py test
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
```

And this issue is not happening when I run my unit tests.

Even when I try to run simple tests like :

```
class FrontTest(LiveServerTestCase):

        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(self):
        super(FrontTest,self).setUpClass()

        @classmethod
        def tearDownClass(self):
        super(FrontTest, self).tearDownClass()

        def test_stupid(self):
            print('hello world')
```

Does this problem ever happened to you ?

Comment: There are quite some posts about related issues with LiveServerTestCase, it can become quite broad. Database, HTTPS, etc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, if you have a link about https, I tried many things but never heard about it. The strange thing is that the problem doesn't happen all the time.